# How to debug a screensaver built with Xcode on OSX 10.11

Tags: xcode, osx-elcapitan, screensaver

Adding `/System/Library/FrameWorks/ScreenSaver.framework/ResourcesScreenSaverEngine.app` as the executable to run against in the schema gives the following error:

> Message from debugger: cannot attach to process due to System
>   Integrity Protection

Is there a better way of working around this than disabling System Integrity Protection altogether?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a duplicate copy of ScreenSaverEngine.app outside of the /System directory hierarchy, and set the scheme's executable to that duplicate app.  The copy of the app does not have SIP attributes, so Xcode can run it under the debugger.